# Hide application on android using DevicePolicyManager

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, device-policy-manager, android-security

I'm attempting to use DevicePolicyManager to hide Facebook on my device from within my application. Right now, I've managed to disable the camera upon a condition by calling the setCameraDisabled method.

Now I'm trying to hide Facebook so I called the setApplicationHidden method and specified Facebook's bundleId as one of the parameters. When I run my code, I get a java Security Exception saying that my admin does not own the profile.

How do I get user permission so I can stop this security exception? Is there a better way to go about programmatically restricting a 3rd party app?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, this has nothing to do with "user permission". For example, to be a device owner, you have to go through a special setup process when first booting the device. Both "profile owner" and "device owner" are part of the Android for Work system.

Comment: did you hide apps using the setApplicationHidden Api? When i tried this api it doesn't hide the app and returned a false value even though my app is a device owner. Do you have any idea why it returns false?

Answer (score 0):

To use methods provided by DevicePolicyManager class we must make the app device owner. I have used dpm command to make my app deviec owner.
following are the steps for it

1. first factory reset device
2. install your app and activate it as admin.
3. from terminal run following command

dpm set-device-owner packageNameOfApp/DeviceAdminRcvrwithFullPackageName

you can find delailed discussion [here](http://florent-dupont.blogspot.in/2015/01/android-shell-command-dpm-device-policy.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use "dpm set-device-owner" on any admin application without any need to factory reset your device.

And remembrer this adb command should be used for test purpose only. Additionally to that admin feature is [no more supported by Google](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin).

You should be either [Device owner](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/provision) or [Profile Owner](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/provision#profile_owner_provisioning) to use any API in [DevicePolicyManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager)

NB: seem that some Manufacture still support Admin feature in there ROM like Samsung even if they use new Android version